# In-App Settings or Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, in-app

What's the better approach, use In-App Settings (A Screen on Startup) or use the Settings Bundle and if nothing is entered show a popup on start? Or is it possible to combine both?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 5):

Apple says:

> Which option you choose depends on how you expect users to interact with preferences. The Settings bundle is generally the preferred mechanism for displaying preferences. However, games and other apps that contain configuration options or other frequently accessed preferences might want to present them inside the app instead.

Therefore if the settings are going to be used frequently use in-app settings, otherwise make a settings bundle

Answer (score 0):

Try [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/), it will provide you a hybrid solution by maintaining the Settings.app pane.